# DB2: SQL to return all rows in a group having a particular value of a column in two latest records of this group

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I have a DB2 table having one of the columns (A) which has either value PQR or XYZ.

I need output where the latest two records based on col C date have value A = PQR.

Sample Table

```
A   B     C
--- ----- ----------
PQR Mark  08/08/2019
PQR Mark  08/01/2019
XYZ Mark  07/01/2019
PQR Joe   10/11/2019
XYZ Joe   10/01/2019
PQR Craig 06/06/2019
PQR Craig 06/20/2019
```

In this sample table, my output would be Mark and Craig records

Comment: format the sample table properly. Its not all readable.

Comment: Did I get it right, that you need all the records for particular name in `B`, if the 2 latest records **for this name** have `PQR` in `A`? And what is the Db2 version?

Comment: Select from table where A = 'PQR', order by C descending and FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Since 11.1

You may use the `nth_value` OLAP function.
Refer to [OLAP specification](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0023461.html).

```
SELECT A, B, C
FROM
(
SELECT 
  A, B, C
, NTH_VALUE (A, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY B ORDER BY C DESC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) C1
, NTH_VALUE (A, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY B ORDER BY C DESC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) C2
FROM TAB
)
WHERE C1 = 'PQR' AND C2 = 'PQR'
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=2da61c8e8189c18275e0244a07b14c38) link.

## Older versions

```
SELECT T.*
FROM TAB T
JOIN 
(
SELECT B
FROM
(
SELECT 
  A, B
, ROWNUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY B ORDER BY C DESC) RN
FROM TAB
)
WHERE RN IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY B
HAVING MIN(A) = MAX(A) AND COUNT(1) = 2 AND MIN(A) = 'PQR'
) G ON G.B = T.B;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! My DB2 version does not recognize this OLAP function.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution could be

```
SELECT A,B,C 
  FROM tab
 WHERE A = 'PQR'
 ORDER BY C DESC FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS only
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! This SQL wont work since i need data for n records and expect more than 2 rows in output.

Comment: Well if you need it describe it - how should anyone know?